# Как наложить текстуру на полигон в OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, шейдеры

Есть шейдер, который устанавливает цвет полигона - треугольника, но я хочу чтобы вместо цвета была текстура, получается мне нужно вместо выходного color вписать мою текстуру? Как это делается, если у меня имеются координаты текстуры?

Вот фрагментный щейдер:

```
#version 330 core 

in vec3 normal_modelspace; 
in vec3 vertex_modelspace; 

out vec3 color; 
uniform vec3 light_worldspace; 

void main() { 
vec3 n = normalize(normal_modelspace); 
vec3 l = normalize(light_worldspace - vertex_modelspace); 
float cosTheta = clamp( dot( n, l), 0,1 ); 
float ambient = 0.05; 

color = vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0) * (cosTheta + ambient); 
}
```

Comment: Вы уже спрашивали ровно то же самое ... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785279

Comment: Вам надо загрузить текстуру в OpenGL, передать в шейдер ее айдишник, в шейдере при помощи сэмплера получить из нее тексель и отобразить его. Посмотрите какой-нибудь урок по текстурированию в OpenGL - там будет все подробно расписано.

Comment: у вас в шейдере нет координат текстур, добавь их и все получится.